# how to create code shortcuts in adobe brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

Does anyone know how to create a quick code shortcut in Brackets? e.g. if in Javascript, if I type "f" and then hit tab, the editor writes the code "function(){}". IntelliJ has something called Live Templates. I wonder if something like this also exists for Brackets.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the extension manager and select the available panel in the dialog. Type "snippet" in the search box and install the Brackets Snippets (by edc). This will come with many predefined snippets but also allow you to create your own in a very simple syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tod! I downloaded and installed Snippets; restarted Brackets and have a light bulb in the right pane but when I click on it to get the Snippets Manager, I get a blankspace. Please see attached pic. DO you know what is the issue? Any feedback is appreciated